# How to use mongo '$or' operator with regex with 2 different keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Working on a search bar to search through a list of items
(items have name and address) in react with mongo

the keys are called 'name' and 'Address'

I want the search bar to to display based on user input, it could be name or address based on regex

But I can only get the query to use one of the keys and not both

```
queryData['name'] = { $regex: searchField.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_@.]/g,''), $options: 'i' } // this lets me search through name array
```

When I change 'name' to address, it will use the address array for searchbar
how can I use both name and address?

I tried doing

```
queryData['$or'] = [
    { name: {regex: searchField.replace(...), $options: 'i' }},
    { address: {regex: searchField.replace(...),$options:'i'}}
]
```

But the above method does not work, no errors on inspector, is my syntax off ?  What else can I try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say does not work, what happens? Do you find results when it's just the name? You likely have some other issues somewhere that's causing issues. (Post the full code/[mcve]).

Comment: it didn't do the search, it should dispaly the input im searching.
I can either set it to search by utilizing the name array or the address array
but both array together does not work

Answer (score 0):

The only thing is that in your syntax you don't have the $ in front of your regex strings. I tried your example on a MongoDB database that I have running locally and it seems to work as long as you use $regex, not regex, so (in my case):

```js
{$or: [{name: {regex: "Energy"}},{category: {regex: "Values"}}]}
```

Comment: The Query by itself works, but I manage to find a workaround by using if statement to use one or the other, it seem mongo might have trouble with $or queries that has regex in side it.
Thanks for the answers
I appreciate it